# iOS7 Navigation bar text colour

Tags: iphone, ios7

I'm having problems changing the text and status bar text colour to white.

I want all the black text to be white,any ideas?

I have seen a lot of solutions but none seem to work on iOS 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what i did..

Do the following to make the status bar text color white through the whole app.

On you project `plist` file:

Status bar style: `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`

`View controller-based status bar appearance: NO`

`Status bar is initially hidden: NO`

No need to implement `preferredStatusBarStyle` or call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` if you want the same behavior throughout the app.

Comment: This is what I needed to do to upgrade a project that was built in xcode 4.6.3. It seems that the defaults don't update to what they usually are for new xcode 5 projects and this fixed it.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78658/is-it-okay-to-copy-paste-answers-from-other-questions

Comment: this won't help with navigation bar title text color

Answer (score 55):

My solution was to add the following to AppDelegate:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];
```

Swift 3:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
```

Swift 5:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
```

In [iOS 13](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/224/) you can set the appearance on a navigation bar itself using `UINavigationBarAppearance`:

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]

navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
```

Answer (score 29):

To turn your title text color white put this in your viewDidLoad

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{UITextAttributeTextColor : [UIColor whiteColor]}
```

To change your Status bars text color to white add this to your view

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

Comment: Great the first part worked but i had to change it to: self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}; but the second part is not working. Am i adding to the AppDelegate.m?

Comment: You should add that to your viewControllers didLoad or willAppear method. You may also need to call [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate]. You could also change the status bar's appearance app wide in your info.plist

Comment: I have added it to my MasterViewController.m viewDidLoad but the status bar text is still black.

Comment: You must have ViewControllerBasedStatusBarApperance set to yes (this is the default). If that is the case you will need to override 
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
in each of your viewControllers. Make sure you return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent if you're looking for white text in your status bar

Answer (score 12):

There are a couple of things you might want to do.

1) To change the color of the title:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]};
```

2) To change the color of Bar buttons:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

3) To make the status bar text color white through the whole app:

On you **project plist** file:

- Status bar style: `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`
- View controller-based status bar appearance: `NO`
- Status bar is initially hidden: `NO`

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName]];
```

Answer (score 3):

Just replace with **`NSForegroundColorAttributeName`** with **`UITextAttributeTextColor`**

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]};
```